# Usage of facing the heat

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, american-english

"If you don't do this task in 2 days, you are gonna face a lot of heat" Is this sentence correct? I have seen uses like take a lot of heat, here I am using face a lot of heat.
The context is like in a company when an employee is given a strict timeline to complete and is delaying things a lot, so it's like suggesting to him, as a friend that it won't go well down the manager.

Comment: "you are gonna face a lot of heat" is quite informal - I wouldn't expect it to be used in a workplace context unless maybe 2 friends are talking informally. Different industries have different norms, but you don't provide much information on where it is to be used (and it will probably vary by country - more likely in US than India).

Comment: We say: You will get a lot of heat for doing x, for example, and not face a lot of heat.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing seriously wrong with the sentence if it is reported speech. The meaning is clear to a native English speaker. If you are writing then it should be "going to" however you pronounce it.
There is a similar, less common phrase, **[hold someone's feet to the fire](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+your+feet+to+the+fire)** which means much the same, to pressurise them to do something.

Comment: Do you mean if I am writing/messaging to someone I should prefer `going to ` instead of `gonna`?

Comment: Also could the face a lot of heat be used, when the seniors may not actually directly criticize the person on the face, but they may take the current situation in a really bad way?

Comment: @nicku Well this is the ELL site so we attempt to show you correct, well spoken English, not accents or dialect! I will admit *gonna* does occasionally appear in written text, in things like the song "I'm *gonna* sit right down and write myself a letter ..." but it's rare. I think "face a lot of heat" is probably only applied to criticism  either face to face or via the management chain. Manager: "the boss says he is very unhappy with your work"

Answer (score 0):

to get or take a lot of heat for doing or not doing something

That is the usual form of the idiom.